# Updating a dataframe rows based on another dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, and one bigger dataframe needs to be updated based on data from smaller dataframe. So basically if there is a record with matching names I want to update the price in df1, just like in an example below. There might be multiple rows with the same name in df1

**df1**

```
id name price 

1 name_1 5,34 

2 name_2 5,36 

3 name_3 4,74 

4 name_4 5,23 

5 name_5 5,94 

6 name_1 5,34
```

**df2**

```
name price 

name_4 5,17 

name_1 5,37
```

**df_result**

```
id name price 

1 name_1 5,37 

2 name_2 5,36 

3 name_3 4,74 

4 name_4 5,17 

5 name_5 5,94 

6 name_1 5,37
```

I'm quite stuck. Tried doing this with df.loc[] but I got nowhere. Any ideas?

Comment: `Tried doing this with df.loc[] but I got nowhere` - add the code from you attempt to your question

Comment: Use `pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['name'], keep='last')`

Comment: Alternatively `df1.merge(df2, on="name", how="left").ffill(axis=1).drop("price_x", axis=1)`

Comment: @jezrael your method doesn't preserve the `"id"` column on the replaced rows (nor the index if that matters). I'm not sure this is an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Dan - Agree, reopened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use update...like so..

```
df1.update(df2)
```

Comment: this could work if you set the index to name first. So `df3 = df1.set_index("name")` and then `df3.update(df2.set_index("name")).reset_index()`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do multiple one-to-one matches, `merge` can help you here:

```py
df1.merge(df2, on="name", how="left").ffill(axis=1).drop("price_x", axis=1)
```

by doing a left join, you keep all the values in df1 that don't have matches in df2. The `ffill` then does null-coallesing where you keep the right most non-null column.

---

Another option based on Sandeep's answer:

```
df3 = df1.set_index("name")
df3.update(df2.set_index("name")).reset_index()
```

Comment: I updated my question. I didn't write one important thing - there are places where there are multiple rows with the same name but with different id

Comment: @TomaszSłowik I think my solution works as is for that case...?

Comment: It does! Thank you :) Had to play around since I have some mess with my data.

Comment: @TomaszSłowik btw check my comment on Sandeeps answer, it might be cleaner for you