# How to update a pandas dataframe with sets, from another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, numpy, dataframe

Trying to update each row from df1 to df2 if unique_value is matched, then based on status from df1, update price in price_array in df2; If not, append the row to df2 and assign new ID column.

This is a part 2 question from: [Iterate each row by updating values from 1st dataframe to 2nd dataframe based on unique value w/ different index, otherwise append and assign new ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198456/iterate-each-row-by-updating-values-from-1st-dataframe-to-2nd-dataframe-based-on)

Note:

active and new: add

suspended and inactive: remove

df1 (NO ID COLUMN):

```
        unique_value        Status        Price
0       xyz123              active        6.67
1       eff987              suspended     1.75
2       efg125              active        5.77
3       xyz123              new           7.55
4       xyz123              inactive      4.55
5       eff987              new           5.55
```

df2:

```
        unique_value        Price_array  ID
0       xyz123              {4.55}       1000
1       xyz985              {1.31}       1001
2       abc987              {4.56}       1002
3       eff987              {1.75}       1003
4       asd541              {8.85}       1004
```

Desired output for updated df2:

```
        unique_value        Price_array       ID
0       xyz123              {6.67,7.55}       1000    <- updated (added 6.67, added 7.55, removed 4.55)
1       xyz985              {1.31}            1001    
2       abc987              {4.56}            1002
3       eff987              {5.55}            1003    <- updated (removed 1.75, added 5.55)
4       asd541              {8.85}            1004
5       efg125              {5.77}            1005    <- appended and new ID assigned
```

Here is the code from part 1: [Iterate each row by updating values from 1st dataframe to 2nd dataframe based on unique value w/ different index, otherwise append and assign new ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198456/iterate-each-row-by-updating-values-from-1st-dataframe-to-2nd-dataframe-based-on)

```
# additional state variables
# 1. for the ID to be added
current_max_id = df2["ID"].max()
# 2. for matching unique_values, avoiding searching df2["unique_value"] every time
current_value_set = set(df2["unique_value"].values)

# match unique_value's using the state variable instead of `df2`
mask = df1["unique_value"].isin(current_value_set)

for i in range(len(df1)):
    
    # current unique_value from df1
    uv1 = df1["unique_value"][i]
    
    # 1. update existing
    if mask[i]:
        
        # broadcast df1 into the matched rows in df2 (mind the shape)
        df2.loc[df2["unique_value"] == uv1, ["unique_value", "Status", "Price"]] = df1.iloc[i, :].values.reshape((1, 3))
        
        #UPDATE PRICE with PRICE_ARRAY
        ...see below

    # 2. append new
    else:
        # update state variables
        current_max_id += 1
        current_value_set.add(uv1)
        # append the row (assumes df2.index=[0,1,2,3,...])
        df2.loc[len(df2), :] = [df1.iloc[i, 0], df1.iloc[i, 1], df1.iloc[i, 2], current_max_id]
```

Is there any way to update the price in df1 to price_array in df2 based on status from df1? I'm thinking something along the line of this ("status" column removed from the broadcast portion of the code):

```
        curr_price=df1.iloc[i,df1.columns.get_loc('Price')]
        if df1.iloc[i,df1.columns.get_loc('Status')] in ('inactive', 'suspended'):
            df2.loc[df2["unique_value"] == uv1,'Price_array'].discard(curr_price)
        else:
            df2.loc[df2["unique_value"] == uv1,'Price_array'].add(curr_price)
```

But got the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-156-6ff78c7a4a9a> in <module>()
     46     if mask[i]:
     47         # Broadcast refresh table into the matched rows in historical
---> 48         df2.loc[df2["unique_value"] == uv1, ["unique_value", "Price"]] = df1.iloc[i, :].values.reshape((1,3))
     49 

/anaconda/envs/pyfull36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    192             key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
    193         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
--> 194         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    195 
    196     def _has_valid_type(self, k, axis):

/anaconda/envs/pyfull36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
    581                     value = np.array(value, dtype=object)
    582                     if len(labels) != value.shape[1]:
--> 583                         raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '
    584                                          'when setting with an ndarray')
    585 

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The following code as 3 main steps:

  1. Setup the dataframes, and `.join` them.
  2. Use `np.where` and `set` math, to update `'Price_array'`.

     - Older versions of pandas raise a `TypeError` when aggregating `set`, as per [Pandas groupby and make set of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572611). This is not an issue in `pandas 1.1.2`.
  3. Fill any missing ID values, using `.update`.

### Setup DataFrames

- This is how they should look to begin with

```py
import pandas as pd

# setup dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_value': ['xyz123', 'eff987', 'efg125', 'xyz123', 'xyz123', 'eff987'], 'Status': ['active', 'suspended', 'active', 'new', 'inactive', 'new'], 'Price': [6.67, 1.75, 5.77, 7.55, 4.55, 5.55]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_value': ['xyz123', 'xyz985', 'abc987', 'eff987', 'asd541'], 'Price_array': [{4.55}, {1.31}, {4.56}, {1.75}, {8.85}], 'ID': [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004]})

# df1
  unique_value     Status  Price
0       xyz123     active   6.67
1       eff987  suspended   1.75
2       efg125     active   5.77
3       xyz123        new   7.55
4       xyz123   inactive   4.55
5       eff987        new   5.55

# df2
  unique_value Price_array    ID
0       xyz123      {4.55}  1000
1       xyz985      {1.31}  1001
2       abc987      {4.56}  1002
3       eff987      {1.75}  1003
4       asd541      {8.85}  1004
```

### setup the dataframes to be joined

```py
# for df2, set unique_value as the index
df2.set_index('unique_value', inplace=True)

# for df1, groupby unique_value and aggregate a set onto Price
df1g = df1.groupby('unique_value').agg({'Price': set})

# join df2 and df1g
dfj = df2.join(df1g, how='outer')

# replace NaN with empty string, '', then replace '', with empty set; NaN can't be directly replace with a set
dfj[['Price_array', 'Price']] = dfj[['Price_array', 'Price']].fillna('').applymap(set)

# dfj
             Price_array      ID               Price
unique_value                                        
abc987            {4.56}  1002.0                  {}
asd541            {8.85}  1004.0                  {}
eff987            {1.75}  1003.0        {1.75, 5.55}
efg125                {}     NaN              {5.77}
xyz123            {4.55}  1000.0  {4.55, 6.67, 7.55}
xyz985            {1.31}  1001.0                  {}
```

### use `np.where` and `set` math to update `'Price_array'`

- If `'Price'` is an empty set `{}`

  - Use `x.Price - x.Price_array`
- Otherwise

  - Use `x.Price_array`
- The order of `set` math, matters

  - `{4.56} - set()` is `{4.56}`
  - `set() - {4.56}` is `set()`

```py
# use np.where and set math to update Price_array
dfj['Price_array'] = dfj[['Price_array', 'Price']].apply(lambda x: np.where(len(x.Price) > 0, x.Price - x.Price_array, x.Price_array), axis=1)

# drop the Price column
dfj.drop(columns=['Price'], inplace=True)

# reset the index
dfj.reset_index(inplace=True)

# dfj
  unique_value   Price_array      ID
0       abc987        {4.56}  1002.0
1       asd541        {8.85}  1004.0
2       eff987        {5.55}  1003.0
3       efg125        {5.77}     NaN
4       xyz123  {6.67, 7.55}  1000.0
5       xyz985        {1.31}  1001.0
```

### fill any missing `'ID'` values

```py
# extract all rows with missing ID
dfjna = dfj.loc[dfj.ID.isna()].copy()

# get the max ID value from the ID column
idm = int(dfj.ID.max())

# update all the missing ID values from a range beginning at idm+1
dfjna.ID = range(idm+1, idm+len(dfjna)+1)

# update the missing ID values in dfj with dfjna
dfj.update(dfjna)

# set the ID column as int
dfj.ID = dfj.ID.astype(int)

# display(dfj)
  unique_value   Price_array    ID
0       abc987        {4.56}  1002
1       asd541        {8.85}  1004
2       eff987        {5.55}  1003
3       efg125        {5.77}  1005
4       xyz123  {6.67, 7.55}  1000
5       xyz985        {1.31}  1001
```

Comment: thanks again for your help! really appreciate it! I will get pandas updated!